# Divide balls in n cells s.t. for every $1\le i \lt n$ there are more balls in cell no. $i$ then in cell no. $i+1$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given an unlimited number of identical balls and $n\gt 10$ cells. In how many ways can you place balls in the $n$ cells such that for every $1\le i \lt n$ there are more balls in cell $i$ than in cell $i+1$ and in every cell there are no more than $k$ balls ($k$ is an integer greater than $n$).

A detailed solution would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint:

Let $a_i$ be the number of balls in cell $n-i+1$. Then it will be helpful to have a look at the sequence $b_i$ defined as

\begin{cases}
b_1 = a_1 \\
b_i = a_i - a_{i-1}-1 \text{ for } 1 < i \leq n \\
b_{n+1} = k-a_n
\end{cases}

If the $a_i$ define a valid placement of balls, what can you say about the $b_i$?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, Ward reversed the indexing that OP had in mind. So $a_i - a_{i-1} -1$ would be negative in the OP's notation. So if you reverse your indices, Ward's suggestion should be good. 

Also, perhaps take these equations and add 1 to all the right hand sides. For me that makes it a little clearer, since it gets rid of the complication that $a_1$ (or $a_n$, in the OP's notation) is allowed to be zero.

Comment: Can you explain the hint? @Eric Auld

Comment: Oops, @EricAuld is right, I was thinking about increasing $a$ instead of decreasing a. I will edit the hint.

Comment: I could just look at the sequence from the other way around but what can I do with it?

Comment: The clue is that the $b_i$ are a sequence of $n+1$ non-negative numbers with a sum of $k-n+1$ if and only if the $a_i$ define a valid placement of the balls. Therefore counting the valid placements is the same as counting sequences of length $n+1$ of non-negative numbers that sum to $k-n+1$.

Comment: Why is that true?

Comment: Just have a look at the sequence. $b_i$ is positive if and only if $a_i > a_{i-1}$ and $b_{n+1}$ is positive if the first cell does not contain more than $k$ balls.

Comment: But why is the sum equal to $k-n+1$?

Comment: Just add all the $b_i$. All the $a_i$ cancel and you are left with $k-(n-1)$.

Comment: I still don't get it. $a_i$ cancel anyway. Can you explain it please?

Comment: I suggest you check the case $n=3$ by hand. Just write down $b_1,\cdots,b_4$, add them, and check that it is equal to k-3+1. It will be clear why it is true for any $n$.

Comment: Alright I did that. As I said, $a_i$ cancel anyway so the sum is $k-n+1$ either way. So why is it if and only if?

Comment: That's right the sum is always $k-n+1$

Comment: So the answer is $S(n+1, k-n+1)$? I don't think that's true

Comment: The "only if" part says that if you have non-negative $b_i$ that sum to $k-n+1$, then you can go back to the $a_i$, and those will be strictly decreasing and less than $k$.

Comment: What do you mean with $S(a,b)$?

Comment: $\binom{k+1}{k-n+1}$

Comment: If I am not mistaken the number of non-negative sequences of length $a$ summing to $b$ is $\binom{a+b-1}{a-1}$, so the answer would be $\binom{k+1}{n}$

Comment: Yeah, so the same as what you wrote.

Comment: @GADI I don't think you want non-negative sequences here, because each bin has to have strictly more balls in it than the previous one. So having a zero in the middle doesn't work.

Comment: That is the reason there is a $-1$ in the middle equation.

Comment: No, if that was the case I would not have defined $b_{n+1}$.

Comment: Great! I get you now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to reverse the indices of the bins, like Ward did.

Let's start with a problem: how many solutions of

$$x_1 + x_2 + \dotsb + x_k = n \quad \text{are there?}$$

Here I'm assuming all the $x_i$ are positive integers. This is a well-known result which I won't explain: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) if you want. The answer is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

Now my strategy for solving your problem is to look for a way to transform it into the above problem. My basic idea is to make $x_i$ "how many balls have been added since the previous bin". But there are two obstacles:

1. Our last bin doesn't need to have a fixed number of balls. (It can have at most $k$, but it could have less than $k$.) So we don't know what number it is that we're splitting up into $n$ parts.
2. The first bin is allowed to have zero balls in it.

Let's fix 2 first by adding one ball to each bin. Now we're doing the same problem, except $k$ is now $k+1$, and every bin needs to have at least one ball. Now we'll fix 1 by introducing a $(n+1)$st bin, that we proclaim has exactly $k+2$ balls in it.

(The reason we choose $k+2$ balls is so it's always at least one bigger than bin $n$, which can have as many as $k+1$.)

Now we've counted the number of ways to break up $k+2$ into $n+1$ parts. That is

$$\textbf{Answer} = \mathbf{\binom{k+1}{n}}$$

The rigorous way to draw a bijection between the $a_i$ and the $x_i$ such that

$$x_1 + \dotsb + x_{n+1} = k+2$$

is to take $x_1 = a_1$, $x_i = a_i - a_{i-1}$ for $2 \leq i \leq n$, and $x_{n+1} = (k+1) - a_n$.